# No signature of method: build_9to1cg5tnfrkz8e8n77tajtyd.android() is applicable for argument

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am receiving an error on my flutter app.
Build file 'D:\Projects\friendlysoul\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_9to1cg5tnfrkz8e8n77tajtyd.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9to1cg5tnfrkz8e8n77tajtyd$_run_closure2) values: [build_9to1cg5tnfrkz8e8n77tajtyd$_run_closure2@a4fb7d1]

It was working fine until yesterday but it showed error I am unable to find any solution on internet

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
      def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
     if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
      localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
    }

        def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
     if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in 
    the local.properties file.")
     }

      def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
      if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

        def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
      if (flutterVersionName == null) {
      flutterVersionName = '1.0'
     }

      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.friendlysoul"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        minSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnable true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding ( ndkVersion "23.1.7779620" ) **After** compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

will be like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

read more about ndk stable Version
Source: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads